# Counting beads in a chain

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Assume we are to order $11$ beads in a chain so that we are using $m$ colours and we have an unlimited supply of each colour, how many different chains can we make?

I know that there is a solution using some group theory (haven't found it though) although I was wondering if there was a much more elementary solution.

Edit: the chain is circular so rotations are considered equal.

Comment: Is the chain a loop? If so, presumably re-arranging it is considered equivalent? Does flipping it count as "the same" chain - is  a chain that goes $RGB$ the same as a chain that goes $GBR$?

Answer (score 0):

For each link in the chain we have $m$ choices, and we have $11$ links that we need to place, so the answer is $$m^{11}$$

Comment: It is not that simple.  You have to take reflections and rotations into account.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig perhaps I misunderstood the question. I assumed that the beads in the chain were ordered.

Comment: Yeah, it is a poorly worded question, because the OP never states when two arrangements are considered "equal," and doesn't even mention that the chain is circular.

Comment: Edited. Excuse me

Answer (score 0):

My idea was to define $G=D_{11}$ and define the set $X:=${all possible colourings of the chains}.

Using Byrn's lemma (don't know the exact name) i'd get $m$ orbits for each rotation (there are $11$ rotations). $m^6$ orbit for each reflection ($10$ of these and at last for the identity we get $m^11$ orbits, therefore according t our lemma we get

${X/G}=(11m+10m^6+m^{11})/22$

Am I right? And is there a more elementary solution?

Comment: Your expression for $X/G$ is not an integer for all $m$:  $11m+10m^6+m^{11}\equiv m(1-m^5)$ mod $11$, so consider $m=2$.

Comment: You'll get a happier result if you recount the number of (nontrivial!) rotations, and also the number of reflections.

Comment: @Barry Cipra So there should be 10 rotations and 11 reflections? Which would give me $10m+11m^6+m^{11}$ my mistake

Comment: Yep.  BTW, the name you were looking for is Burnside.